# Web view problems

Tags: android, android-webview

I have some problem in my web view.
I want to load a string from a WordPress blog, witch have html tags such as `<a>` and image tag and ... .
So my problems are:

1. As I mention above, I want to load a local string and I want to handle user click on the links, so I load data like this into the web view:

   ```
   WebView webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.mainWV);
   webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

   String s="<p>It will<a href=\"http://www.bbc.com/\"> enable</a> Seattle-based Alaska to expand into lucrative hubs such</p>\n<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-1035\" src=\"http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/D09F/production/_89070435_89069565.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"120\" /></p>\n<p>as San Francisco and Los Angeles.</p>\n"; 

   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", s, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
   ```

   and another way I tried was:

   ```
    String head1 = "<head></head>";
       String text = "<html>" + head1
               + "<body  dir=\"rtl\" >" + s
               + "</body></html>";
   ```

   webview.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");

   and my client is :

   ```
    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           Log.d("USER_CLICKED", url + "USER_CLICKED");
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

   Ok, now when I run the app, and when I click on `<a>` I never see 'USER_CLICKED', but the webview content change and it seems web view is empty, I mean is white as snow.
   notice 1: when I try this:

   ```
   webview.loadUrl("https://android-arsenal.com/");
   ```

   and run the app, when I click on the links in the loaded web view, every thing is OK, and i see this Log: 'USER_CLICKED' and the related URL.
   notice 2: yes i try a lots of different URL, but loading from string, nothings  change in click handling.
   notice 3: I test in android 5.1 and 4.1 in 4.1 clicked recognized and is see 'User.. but in the 5.1 the white page story happens.(Edit: android 6 also do not show 'USER... ')
2. my number 2 problem is, when I call this:

   ```
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", s, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
   ```

   the image tag does not load! I mean it is just ignore to load the images, and I do not know why.
   notice 3: when I copy text from inside the web view there is some rectangle in the text.

Answer (score 1):

OK every one, after a long time, i find the problem, so as i mentioned above, i take string from WordPress rest API(json), so in my word, the string should be OK, but as i find out, there is some extra '\' in the string, and the string is like:

```
<p>It will<a href=\\\"example URL\\\"> enable</a> Seattle....
```

, as simple it is i just use:
  s=s.replaceAll("\\","");
so, thank any one who see this post.

Answer (score 0):

A URL is a URL. The first item is HTML, not a URL. If you want to load the URL then you have to pass a valid URL (not HTML) and do not expect the URL to be magically parsed out of the HTML string that you are loading. In fact the first item is not even valid HTML, it is a part of HTML, potentially a snippet, but it's not even enclosed in the HTML tags that I expect a web view would need.

Comment: thanks for the comment, oh, i tried a bunch of different way before, in fact  i add another way i tested into the question.